# change font in web part

Tags: web-part, calendar, css

Is there a way to change the font in OWA web part for calendar? The fonts are so big and wont fit in the area where web part is. Please suggest.

[image]

Comment: You need to find what css class (or styling) making that effect and then add Content Editor WebPart and put css to override it. If you provide the source html, we can better guide you. You can view the page source and paste it in http://pastebin.com/ and let us know the url.

Answer (score 2):

**edit - sorry, don't know how I missed the OWA part. This doesn't seem to work in that case

you can change the text size by adding your css code to the content editor web part using the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2{font-size:10pt;}</style>
```

The only part you should have to change is the number after this: #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ. You can check by going to view source and Find: #MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ at the start of your calendar view and just use the number that appears after.

I'm not sure if this is the most reliable method but it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by modifying the CSS, you just need to find the style that's controlling it, I always use firebug lite (add on for Google Chrome or FF) to do this.

This is assuming you are using your own Bespoke CSS on the master page as its best not to mess around with the original CSS file.

Hope this helps.

S